No owin.Environment item was found in the context Error while connecting to Identity server in Sitecore 10.3
My Sitecore instance is running in XM scaled mode in local (version 10.3). Earlier Identity server was not in use and disabled in CM site. Now I am trying to install Identity server and connect to CM server in my local .
I did following Steps:

Updated sc.variable identityServerAuthority in Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config with identity site hostname. Also checked setting name="Owin.Authentication.Enabled" value="true" security:require="Sitecore"

Deleted Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler.config.disabler.config and Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config

Added below keys in Appsettings key="owin:appStartup" value="Sitecore.Owin.Startup, Sitecore.Owin" and key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"

In Identity server updated production/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml file with CM server details and client secret.


But I am getting below error on /sitecore/login page and its not redirecting to identity server site.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: No owin.Environment item was found in the context.
Source: Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
   at System.Web.HttpContextExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpContext context) in /_/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/HttpContextExtensions.cs:line 31
   at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager.get_User()
   at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager.GetShellUser()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.BeginDiagnostics.ResolveUser()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.BeginDiagnostics.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Web.RequestEventsHandler.OnPostAuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

